# Problems with workflow: subdivision surface on a mesh

Tags: workflow

this is a refresh from my first question.

I think the question is, wich is the workflow for making a hole into a mesh.

If i model the dome, and then I apply a boolean. That makes a lot of problems. it's impossible to apply the subsurface modifier and in render mode, i see lots of problems.

The goal is that image, but well done

[image: dome]

And this is how it looks in edit mode

[image: edit mode]

Thanks!

Comment: Hello :). The main problem here are the n-gons (faces with more than 4 edges). Subdivision doesn't work well with them and creates those ugly artifacts. Boolean is known for creating n-gons, that have to be cleaned up after.